# Overflow inset?

Tags: html, css

We have a normal `overflow` rule that prevents stuff being visible outside of a container, however, I'm wondering what are the approaches to make a kind of a `overflow: inset` style?

I mean, for example, a `:before` element that is shaped like a triangle animates from beneath a container (slides down) and then animates back up (slides up), but the part of the triangle which is under the container is becoming hidden while the part which is not under it is still visible.

Example use case: the rectangle is a semi-transparent container

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/7dnqour1/ ? I was gonna answer with that but I'm not 100% that's what you want.

Comment: @Aeolingamenfel Nope. If on the red rectangle you set the alpha channel value to less than 1 you'll see the green box. I need the green box to become hidden. Like a clipping effect or smthing

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. The green box does become hidden? Do you mean hidden if it goes out of the red box?

Comment: If you change the opacity of the red rectangle to e.g. `0.5` you will see that when the green rectangle goes under the red one it is visible. What I want is the the part of the green rectangle that is under the red one to be hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want. Basically needed a wrapper around the box that slides up with `overflow: hidden;` to stop it showing when it slides outside the original box.

```css
#red {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#green-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
#green {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  animation: up-and-down 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes up-and-down {
  0% {
    bottom: 0;
  }
  50% {
    bottom: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="green-wrapper">
  <div id="green"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, thought about this. I'll accept this as the answer cause this would work, but I think you should add that in a real life scenario `red` and `green-wrapper` most probably would be wrapped in a `wrapper`. However, in my case, the real effect was made by using `scale()` and changing `transform-origin`. Still thanks for this option. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this, i used in few projects.

```
@keyframes overflowTransition {
  0% {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  100% {
    overflow: visible;
  }
}

.container {
  animation-name: overflowTransition;
  animation-duration: 400ms;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Comment: This would still make a part of the moving element visible while it animates.